# Displaying Hindi UNICODE characters using wglUseFontBitmaps

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, graphics, unicode, fonts

**Background:**
In our C++ game, we use wglUseFontBitmaps to display the character bitmaps on the screen.

Since it's a multiple language game, we create display lists for all the UNICODE characters that our game uses in it's life cycle.

**Problem:**
The problem is when we have glyphs which are combination of more than one characters. Even though we have display lists for all the corresponding characters that make up the glyph, the glyph is displayed as individual characters rather than one combined glyph. For eg. we have a character नौ which is a combination of न and vowel sound ौ. We have created display lists for both characters न (2344) and  ौ (2380). On the screen, instead of showing the combined glyph नौ, it is rendered as two separate glyphs न ौ .

Am I missing something here, any nudge in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "right direction" would be to stop using `wglUseFontBitmaps`. This is not a function intended for serious, production use. I'm surprised that it even draws Unicode glyphs; I'm not surprised that it doesn't handle combining characters at all.

You need a text layout system that actually handles all of Unicode. WGL's stuff isn't going to help you.

Comment: So any better alternatives to render UNICODE characters?